# MySQL joining tables of different structure

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I am having trouble either getting any result or a correct result in the following problem - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/696ed2/4

Overall goal is to list all transactions of users who are linked together as 'Customers'. So if John is looking at his dashboard, he will see which books Alice (his customer) has rented (including book title), and which books were sold (he won't be able to see the title of that book).

When two multiple tables are joined to the parent table, where both depending tables have an 'active' flag set against each row, I can't seem to get only active rows.

```
# USERS 
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` boolean DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `active`) VALUES
(1, 'John', 1),
(2, 'Alice', 1),
(3, 'Jess', 1),
(4, 'Bob', 1);

# BOOKS 
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` boolean DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `books` (`id`, `name`, `active`) VALUES
(1, 'On the Road', 1),
(2, 'Neuromancer', 0),
(3, 'Modern History', 1),
(4, 'Red Mars', 1);

# TRANSACTIONS
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_2_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `book_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum('Rent', 'Sold') NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `transactions` (`id`, `user_1_id`, `user_2_id`, `book_id`,     `timestamp`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 1, '1465238591', 'Rent'),
(2, 2, 1, 2, '1465238592', 'Rent'),
(3, 2, 3, 3, '1465238593', 'Rent'),
(4, 3, 4, NULL, '1465238594', 'Sold'),
(5, 2, 3, NULL, '1465238595', 'Sold'),
(6, 3, 4, NULL, '1465238596', 'Sold'),
(7, 2, 2, 4, '1465238597', 'Rent'),
(8, 1, 3, 1, '1465238598', 'Rent'),
(9, 2, 4, 2, '1465238598', 'Rent');

# RELATIONSHIPS
CREATE TABLE `relationships` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_1_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_2_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('Customer', 'Supplier') NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `relationships` (`id`, `user_1_id`, `user_2_id`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 'Customer'),
(2, 2, 1, 'Customer'),
(3, 2, 4, 'Customer'),
(3, 1, 4, 'Supplier'),
(3, 3, 1, 'Customer');
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  t.id,
  t.type,
  t.timestamp,
  u1.name as user_1_name,
  u2.name as user_2_name,
  b.name as book_name
  FROM transactions t

  LEFT JOIN relationships r ON (r.user_1_id = 1 AND r.type = 'Customer')
  LEFT JOIN books b ON (b.id = t.book_id AND b.active)
  LEFT JOIN users u1 ON (u1.id = t.user_1_id) # AND u1.active
  LEFT JOIN users u2 ON (u2.id = t.user_2_id) # AND u2.active

  WHERE (r.user_2_id = t.user_1_id OR t.user_2_id = 1 AND t.user_1_id != 1)
    # AND b.active AND u1.active AND u2.active
```

**[Result]**:

```
| id | type |  timestamp | user_1_name | user_2_name |      book_name |
|----|------|------------|-------------|-------------|----------------|
|  3 | Rent | 1465238593 |       Alice |        Jess | Modern History |
|  2 | Rent | 1465238592 |       Alice |        John |         (null) | <<< Should not be here
|  7 | Rent | 1465238597 |       Alice |       Alice |       Red Mars |
|  5 | Sold | 1465238595 |       Alice |        Jess |         (null) | <<< Correct
|  9 | Rent | 1465238598 |       Alice |         Bob |         (null) | <<< Should not be here
```

In the above result, the problem is that book Neuromancer has flag 'active' set to 0, so should not appear in the result. I have played with placing `AND b.active` at different places, but the results are always wrong. (See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/696ed2/5)

Looking at the mess above, I am not even sure my approach is any good, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I think you need to enable next line: `# AND b.active AND u1.active AND u2.active`, but use `b.active = 1 AND u1.active = 1 AND u2.active = 1` instead. Also, what is your goal, it is not too clear what you want to get from the query?

Comment: Thank you. If I do enable that line, row marked as ```<<< Correct``` will also disappear, which is not what I need. Overall goal is, in short, to see all transactions of users who are linked as 'Customers'. I have now updated the question to show that.

Comment: I see, so then add `b.active = 1 OR b.active IS NULL`. The complete restriction should be: `(b.active = 1 OR b.active IS NULL) AND u1.active = 1 AND u2.active = 1`. I do not made an answer because still do not fully understand your goal (my mind is on rest mode, lol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As D. Smania mentioned in comments you need to make sure `b.active` is either `1` or `NULL` but based on your `LEFT JOIN` condition `b.active` will always be `1` so you need to do the join only on `id` and rely on the `WHERE` condition for comparison. This should yield the results you asked for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t.id,
    t.type,
    t.timestamp,
    u1.name AS user_1_name,
    u2.name AS user_2_name,
    b.name AS book_name
FROM transactions t
    LEFT JOIN relationships r ON (r.user_1_id = 1 AND r.type = 'Customer')
    LEFT JOIN books b ON (b.id = t.book_id)
    LEFT JOIN users u1 ON (u1.id = t.user_1_id)
    LEFT JOIN users u2 ON (u2.id = t.user_2_id)
WHERE (r.user_2_id = t.user_1_id OR t.user_2_id = 1 AND t.user_1_id != 1)
    AND (b.active OR b.active IS NULL)
    AND u1.active AND u2.active
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/696ed2/8)

One note - in your first `WHERE` condition it's not clear to me whether you mean:

```
(r.user_2_id = t.user_1_id OR (t.user_2_id = 1 AND t.user_1_id != 1))
```

or

```
((r.user_2_id = t.user_1_id OR t.user_2_id = 1) AND t.user_1_id != 1)
```

It's always best to be explicit with your logic grouping when you have adjacent `AND` and `OR`  conditions.